# Google Analytics Virtual Pageview with two onClick actions

Tags: javascript, php, google-analytics, analytics

I have been trying to get the following code to work:

```
<button type="button" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this); _gaq.push(['_trackPageview','/checkout/addtocart/'])">
```

The submit action is working as it should, but the Virtual PageView is not working at all.

Comment: Your code is not displaying.

Answer (score 2):

Check the code on your site.  Your analytics code might be run using a diffrent Variable name. For example on my site its:

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, I would suggest [event tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide) would be a better way to track this as it won't inflate the total pageviews and gives you more insight.

Comment: I would use events except for me wanting to do a funnel analysis.